# Handling ViewExpiredException inside a portlet

Tags: java, jsf, portlet, jsf-1.2, jboss-portal

Is it possible to handle a [`ViewExpiredException`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ViewExpiredException.html) inside a portlet to display an appropriate error page?

We're using JSF 1.2, Portlet API 2.0 and JBoss PortletBridge 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.

But I hope to be wrong...